# Rendering multiple TextInput when fetching JSON - React Native

Tags: json, react-native, fetch, textinput, react-native-flatlist

Is it possible to render multiple TextInputs from an API using React-Native? 
I am working on a project which fetches JSON from an API and first displays a list of Items (Only the title) using FlatList, then I click in one of them and navigates to next page which shows details of that selected item. 
However, there will be continuously new documents added in API which contains a different number of TextInputs, some might have 3, some 2 and so on. Document contains also a title, text, image but those will always be the same amount 1.

**JSON file I am fetching from API:**

```
{  
  "results":[  
  {  

     "contract":{  
        "title":"Contract test",
        "content":"You can always follow the progress of your application 
  by logging on the the application portal."
     },

    "fillable_fields": {
        "FIELD_NAME_1": "FIELD_VALUE_1",
        "FIELD_NAME_2": "FIELD_VALUE_2",
        "FIELD_NAME_N": "FIELD_VALUE_N"
    },
     "picture":{  

 "medium":"https://www.healthcaredenmark.dk/media/11272/bridgeit_logo.png"
     }
  }
]
}
```

**My code:**

```
class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Content of selected'
    };

    render() {
      const source = this.props.navigation.state.params.source;
      const item = this.props.navigation.state.params.item;
      let contract = "";
      let img = "";
      let inp = "";
      let content ="";

      if (item != null) {
        contractTitle = item.contract.title;
        img = item.picture.medium;
        content = item.contract.content;
        inp = item.fillable_fields
      }

      return (   
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>{contractTitle} </Text>
          <Image
            style={{width: 300, height: 128}}
            source={{uri: img}}
          />

          <Text  style={styles.text} > {content} </Text>
          <FlatList>
            <TextInput style={{textAlign: 'center', borderWidth: 1, marginBottom: 7, height: 50}}>
              {inp}
            </TextInput>
          </FlatList>

          <Button title="Go back to the list" onPress={this._goHome}/>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you should try this:

```
renderInputFields = () => {
    let inputFieldsList = [];
    let arrayFromJson = //extract here your input fields array from JSON
    arrayFromJson.map((inputFieldItem) => {
         inputFieldsList.push(
             <TextInput style={{textAlign: 'center', borderWidth: 1, marginBottom: 7, height: 50}}>
                 {inputFieldItem.text} //.text is example. you should use here what property you need
             </TextInput>)
    });

    return inputFieldsList;
}

 <FlatList>
     {this.renderInputFields()}
 </FlatList>
```

Let me know if you have any question, or something is not clear.

Comment: please check below!